# How can I increase the speed/efficiency of these UPS queries?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, tracking, ups

Someone else before me wrote a program that takes a bunch of UPS tracking #'s and queries UPS for the status of these. The problem is, with time this program has grown more complex. These queries are now taking too long. It takes about 350ms per query, and some pages have nearly 40 queries, taking about ~15 seconds to load per page.

The method takes in a tracking # as a string and then makes some sort of xml request to UPS which returns the correct data, just very slowly.

Here is the code:

```
public static List<string> MakeRequest(string tracking)
{
    List<string> res = new List<string>();

    string xmlStringRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                      "<AccessRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">" +
                      "<AccessLicenseNumber>apilicense</AccessLicenseNumber>" +
                      "<UserId>apiusername</UserId>" +
                      "<Password>apipassword</Password>" +
                      "</AccessRequest>" +
                      "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                      "<TrackRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">" +
                      "<Request>" +
                      "<TransactionReference>" +
                      "<CustomerContext>Your Test Case Summary Description</CustomerContext>" +
                      "<XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>" +
                      "</TransactionReference>" +
                      "<RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>" +
                      "<RequestOption>1</RequestOption>" +
                      "</Request>" +
                      "<TrackingNumber>" + tracking + "</TrackingNumber>" +
                      "</TrackRequest>";

    ASCIIEncoding encodedData = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] byteArray = encodedData.GetBytes(xmlStringRequest);

    //Create Request
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track");
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.KeepAlive = false;

    //wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wr.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        //Send XML
        Stream SendStream = wr.GetRequestStream();
        SendStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        SendStream.Close();

        //Get Response
        WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        //Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());

        xmlDoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());

        XmlNode nl = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ResponseStatusCode").Item(0);
        response.Close();

        if (nl.InnerText == "1")
        {
            XmlNode del = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ActivityLocation").Item(0);
            XmlNodeList act = del.ChildNodes;

            foreach (XmlNode n in act)
            {
                if (n.Name == "Code")
                {
                    res.Add(n.InnerText);
                }
                else if (n.Name == "Description")
                {
                    res.Add(n.InnerText);
                }
                else if (n.Name == "SignedForByName")
                {
                    res.Add(n.InnerText);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }


            res.Add(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Date").Item(0).InnerText);
            res.Add(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Time").Item(0).InnerText);
        }
        else
        {
            res.Add("Tracking Info Not Available");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        xmlDoc = null;
    }

    return res;
}
```

I stepped through the code, and what seems to take the longest is this line:

```
SendStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Is there an obvious way to increase the speed/efficiency of this query? I'm more familiar with jSON than XML.

Comment: Consult the API documentation and see if there is a batch call that allows multiple lookups in a single request, there is not much else to say if the bottleneck is on the UPS end.

Comment: You current code leaves many streams undisposed, this could cause problems and should be fixed.

Comment: Forking off queries to run in parallel may be another option

Comment: @AlexK.Could you show me an example of one?

Comment: @AlexK. Okay I see what you mean now actually.